# Using localStorage with Next.js before componentDidMount

Tags: reactjs, next.js

We're building an application where we need to store some data in localStorage before componentDidMount is invoked. Is there a way of doing this? It's to store some settings required for various API calls.

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs, your React component's [lifecycle will happen in this order](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#mounting). While you could trigger the save to `localStorage` in in the constructor, or in `getDerivedStateFromProps`, it sounds like you might want to wait to make the API calls that are being made in `componentDidMount` until later. You could set up your chain of logic to only fire the API call once `localStorage` has been written to successfully?